# Как найти текст по маске - числа с разделителями?

Tags: python, маска

Как найти текст по маске - `**.**.****`, где `*`-это цифры?

Comment: можно так:`res = [el for el in text.split() if all(map(str.isdigit, el.split(".")))]` но лучше использовать регулярные выражение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

s = "01.01.2021 мы будем традиционно праздновать Новый Год, а 07.01.2021 Рождество!"
res = re.findall(r"(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})", s)
print(res)
```

вывод:

```
['01.01.2021', '07.01.2021']
```